# SQL Query for searching

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to search some data from my classifieds database, suppose i want to search taj hotel then ,taj hotel should come at the top. But all the hotels get retrieved and the taj hotel is on the next page or on the other positions according to the query i have used.
My query is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_user_products 
 WHERE     (company_name='$a') 
        OR (product_name='$a') 
        OR (   company_name like '%$a%' 
           OR category like '%$a%' 
           OR subcategory like '%$a%' 
           OR title like '%$a%' 
           OR description like '%$a%' 
           OR website like '%$a%'
           OR product_name like '%$a%')  
       AND (city='$cityselect')
 LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage
```

Please suggest me something which could work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090217/how-to-select-record-whose-matching-percentage-is-higher-than-other-using-like-o

Comment: It sounds like you are basically searching every field in your table for a loose match and make no attempt at sorting your results. You really need to look into MySQL natural language matching for this type of search.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
order by FIELD(field_name,'taj') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say the `taj hotel` is the `title` in your `tbl_user_products` then you can use `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY FIELD(title,'$a') DESC
```

UPDATE:

> what is field here pls explain more

The manual says [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found

But in this case with `ORDER BY` the first argument of the `FIELD` is the column name from your table and the other argument(s) could be the order of the values in custom manner.

For example, if you give `ORDER BY FIELD(title,'taj','park','continental',) DESC` it will show all records that has title `continental` first and then `park` and then `taj` and then in alphabetical order

Comment: what is field here pls explain more

Comment: @dholakiyaankit check the update, hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all hotels in a specific city then you should not put a condition on a field, which contains "hotel" details instead apply order by on that field.

Suppose hotel details exists in field1 then you can keep desired hotel on top position even you can keep multiple desired hotels on top as per below-

order by field(field1,'Taj') Desc  -- it will keep Taj on top

order by field(field1,'Trident','Taj') -- It will keep Taj on top then Trident on 2nd position from top.

Comment: it's not working with my query above....????

Comment: let me know in which field 'taj' (hotel informatinon) exists...

Comment: it exists in company name and product name field of the table and i am also using explode to match more than one keyword.

Comment: @a seems a parameter in which you are passing values, please let me know this variable contains multiple value or single value means only 'Taj' or Taj,trident, oberao etc....if you provide resultset of your query then it will much help to identify problem.